# Resetar SetInterval em Carrossel de imagens ao apertar botão não funciona(carrossel com avanço automatico e manual)

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, carousel

```js
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="carousel__item"]')
const nextButton = document.querySelector('[data-js="carousel__button--next"]')
const prevButton = document.querySelector('[data-js="carousel__button--prev"]')
const lastSlideIndex = slides.length - 1

let timer = 2000

let currentSlideIndex = 0

// Manipula as classes tirando e adicionando a classe pra ficar visivel nas imagens
const manipulateSlideClasses = correctSlideIndex => {
  slides.forEach(slide => slide.classList.remove('carousel__item--visible'))
  slides[correctSlideIndex].classList.add('carousel__item--visible')
}

// Evento de apertar Botão de avançar slide
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const correctSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex ?
    currentSlideIndex = 0 :
    ++currentSlideIndex
  manipulateSlideClasses(correctSlideIndex)

})

// Evento de apertar botão de retroceder slide
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const correctSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex === 0 ?
    currentSlideIndex = lastSlideIndex :
    --currentSlideIndex
  manipulateSlideClasses(correctSlideIndex)
})

const intervalLogic = function() {

  nextImage()
}
// função nextImage passa os slides automaticamente
function nextImage() {
  const correctSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex === lastSlideIndex ?
    currentSlideIndex = 0 :
    ++currentSlideIndex
  manipulateSlideClasses(correctSlideIndex)
}


// abaixo a variavel que iniciei aqui fora myTimer pra ver se resolvia a questão do clearInterval
let myTimer
//função start inicia quando a pagina carrega, nessa função start que tudo começa


function start() {

  myTimer = setInterval(intervalLogic, timer)

}

window.addEventListener('load', start)
```

```css
.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel .carousel__item,
.carousel .carousel__item--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.carousel .carousel__item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel .carousel__item--visible {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeVisibility 0.5s;
}

.carousel .carousel__actions {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel .carousel__actions button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #242424;
}

.carousel .carousel__actions button[data-js="carousel__button--prev"] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.carousel .carousel__actions button[data-js="carousel__button--next"] {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

@keyframes fadeVisibility {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: opacity linear;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Exercício 36</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div data-js="carousel__item" class="carousel__item carousel__item--visible">
      <img src="./img/1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div data-js="carousel__item" class="carousel__item">
      <img src="./img/2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div data-js="carousel__item" class="carousel__item">
      <img src="./img/3.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel__actions">
      <button data-js="carousel__button--prev" aria-label="Slide anterior">
                <
                </button>

      <button data-js="carousel__button--next" aria-label="Próximo slide">
                >
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ola pessoal estou com uma duvida e dificuldade aqui, implementei um codigo de carrossel de imagem com JS puro com dois botões pra avançar e retroceder slide(imagem do carrossel), quando eu aperto os botões ele funciona normalmente, mas ai..., implementei uma funcionalidade que faz os slides avançar automaticamente em um periodo de tempo com o setInterval() porém o que eu quero fazer agora pra concluir esse projeto é que o slide automatico continue passando, mas quando eu aperto o botão de retroceder ou avançar slide, o timer do setInterval seja resetado..., nao estou conseguindo implementar isso estou com problemas se puderem me ajuda com a solução agradeceria muito, abaixo estara o codigo em JS

OBS: gostaria de usar somente o JS pra solucionar esse problema

OBS2: não consegui chamar o clearInterval de dentro do setInterval pois não estavam em escopo global, mas quando setei uma variavel global mesmo assim não funcionou

abaixo o codigo da minha ultima implementação que é com o avanço automatico mas com execeção do reset que não consegui e fiquei na duvida

**abaixo os codigos em JS, HTML, CSS**